# Googlemap Places autocomplete full screen activity customization

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I have some places already saved by the app users in SQLite. I want to display those places for selection in the autocomplete Full Screen Activity so that user can select those places and it should be displayed on the google maps. I'm using the following code.

```
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                .build(getContext());


        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

How can i inject my list of already saved places or I can redesign the whole places autocomplete activity.